# How to access eks cluster from local machine

Tags: amazon-eks, eksctl

I have created a EKS cluster and able to run the `kubectl` commands from my ec2 instance. I have then downloaded the `config` file from `~/.kube/config` location to my local machine. I am not able to run the `kubectl` commands and getting authentication error.

What is the right way to access an EKS cluster from local machine.

Comment: have you tried following AWS' [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-cluster-connection/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try look into `users` section in ~/.kube/config, check the `user` under the `name` of the cluster, make sure your local machine has the same working profile as the EC2 instance.

```
...
command: aws
env:
- name: AWS_PROFILE
  value: <make sure this entry is valid on your local machine>
```

If this doesn't work, can you briefly describe how you configured kubeconfig on the EC2 instance in your question.